# Using Ajax and jQuery to check if file exists - always returns 200 response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I'm need to check whether a file exists before showing specific data to clients...using jQuery I have this:

```
<script>
function fileExists(fileLocation) {
    var response = $.ajax({
        url: fileLocation,
        type: 'HEAD',
        async: false
    }).status;
    alert(response);
}
</script>
```

When I attempt to run the function:

```
<script> fileExists('http://www.example.com/123.jpg'); </script>
```

(where example.com is my domain), I ALWAYS receive a 200 response code.  I was wondering why this might be happening - could it be that I have a custom error page set through .htaccess?  Or, is there a better method to do this?

**Note**: jQuery 1.5.1 is being used.

**Update**: It seems it is being directed to our custom error page set through .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.com/errors/notfound.php
```

Not sure if this causes the conflict, or how to get around it.

**SOLVED**

I checked the headers for my custom 404 page, it was returning a 200 response code.  Had to hard code the header:

```
<?php header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found'); ?>
```

which would then return the 404 response code - fixing my issue.

Comment: Happens even when the file does not exist?

Comment: Yes, for example: 123.jpg does not exist on the server, but it returns a 200 status code anyway.

Comment: Sounds like the server isn't setup correctly. What happens when you GET that resource? Do you still get a 200, but with content that suggests 404? In which case that sounds like incorrect config.

Comment: Tried using GET, still no dice - 
    `<script>
         function fileExists(fileLocation) {
      $.ajax({
                 type: 'GET',
                 url: fileLocation,
                 success: function() {
                     alert('Page found.');
                 }, 
                 error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                     log(jqXHR);
                     log(errorThrown);

                 }
            });

        }
    </script>`

Comment: Hey, @pennstate_fanboy. It’s great that you solved your issue — please post it as an answer and accept it, instead of adding the answer to the question.

Comment: Below 100 rep - can't post an answer for another 6hrs, couldn't think of a better method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appeared my issued existed with my custom 404 page, which was returning a 200 status code.  I had to hard code the 404 response code using the php header() function, which resolved the issue I was having.  Now if the page does not exists it follows correctly:

Using a simple method to test if page/file exists for the moment:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'HEAD',
    url: 'http://www.example.com/index.php',
    success: function() {
        alert('Page found.');
    },  
    error: function() {
        alert('Page not found.');
    }
});
```

Thanks to @kalyfe for the suggestion to switch to async method.

Comment: Since PHP 5.4, you can use `http_response_code(404);` to set a 404 status code.

Comment: There is another more secure way. If you use security to limit file access to the client side request. Point to a php file and send the file path as a post variable or whichever your flavor. Then you can filter check the post var and output a custom val to work around the client denied access security. This also would/should grant limited access to client side. As always check input for allowed chars and length. I will post an answer when I build it.

Answer (score 10):

Why don't you realize this asynchronously with the callbacks [success and error](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)?

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'HEAD',
   url: fileLocation,
   success: function(msg){
     alert(msg);
   },
   error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
     log(jqXHR);
     log(errorThrown);

   }
 });
```

Comment: Using your method I can see that it's seeing our custom 404 error page, and returning a 200 as a result.  Any way around this?

Comment: Note: Not doing anything crazy in .htaccess for this -- `ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.com/errors/notfound.php`

Answer (score 0):

What about [`$.get`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), which is just a shorthand for jQuery Ajax?

```js
// this file exists
$.get('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/75/Woman_mechanic_working_on_engine_%28cropped%29.jpeg')
  .done(() => {console.log('file exists')})
  .fail(() => {console.log('File does not exist')}
)

// this file does not exist
$.get('https://example.com/inexistent.jpg')
  .done(() => {console.log('file exists')})
  .fail(() => {console.log('File does not exist')}
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The nice thing here is that the browser fetches the image in the browser, thus you don't need to load it twice when you use it, for example, for html tag `img`. Here na example:

```js
$('#myButton').click(()=>{

  let imgUrl = $('#imgUrl').val();
  
  $.get(imgUrl)
  .done(() => {
    $('img').attr('src', imgUrl);
    $('#imgText').text('');
  })
  .fail(() => {
    $('#imgText').text('Image does not exist');
    $('img').attr('src', '');
  })

})
```

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Image url: <input type="text" id="imgUrl" value="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/75/Woman_mechanic_working_on_engine_%28cropped%29.jpeg"><br>

<button id="myButton" type="button">click here to load image</button>

<div id="imgText"></div>
<img>
```

Answer (score -1):

Async/Await Function

This is kind of a modern way to do this. I was looking to find the best future proof workaround for the depreciated synchronous XHR and AJAX.

Personally I need security so certain files are unavailable to the public. This means that a client side function just wont work. I need a server-side script to check if these files exist.

I've looked around and had a hard time finding this for what I needed it to do. There are well documented other uses, but this one helped me and can be used as another way to solve the OP's question/problem.

```
async function fetchAsync (q) {
  // await response of fetch call 
  // Your file now can get the file name to check via server side if it is there.
  let response = await fetch('https://yoursite.com/check_exists.php?'+q+(q==''?'':'&')+'time='+(new Date().getTime()));
  // only proceed once promise is resolved
  let data = await response.json();
  // only proceed once second promise is resolved
  return data;
}
var myFilePath = 'images/dingle.gif';
// trigger async function
// log response or catch error of fetch promise
fetchAsync('filepath='+myFilePath+'')
    .then(data => {
                 //
                 console.log(data.myJsonVar);
           if(data.myJsonVar == 1){ // the php file should check and return {"myJsonVar":1} if it found the file in question or {"myJsonVar":0}
                // Run scripts or functions about here...
                // For me it is to check if the file exists before an upload.
                // This saves the upload from failing after it is uploaded because it is a duplicate.
           }else{
                 // I run my upload script and functions
           }

     }
})
.catch(reason => console.log(reason.message))
```

I want to point out that you can have any number of variables in the json response from the PHP file. However the smaller amount the better as always.