# jQuery Ajax call with multiple URLs

Tags: jquery, ajax, url

I want to run a Ajax call, but I am having issue locating the script.php file because of my htaccess rewrite rules. I have a index.php, script.php and .htaccess in the same folder.
In the htaccess, there is a RewriteRule which formats a URL like this "domain.com/index.php?bla=123" into this "domain.com/123".

However, my javascript cannot locate the PHP-Script since the path is set to "script.php"  when the URL becomes "domain.com/asdf/". Any idea how to run the script from the js whether through the root or a FAKE directory.

```
url: "script.php" || "../script.php",
```

Comment: Why would you need to do this? You should know where your script file is located.

Comment: So you run a call, and if it 404's run the other call?

Comment: you want a random output ?and wr is the condition ?

Comment: I know where my file is located, but i have a special rule with my htaccess.

Comment: I don't want to run everytime 2 calls for one check, isn't there any other options to check which of the paths are available.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473387/using-ajax-and-jquery-to-check-if-file-exists-always-returns-200-response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the further explanation of your situation, you should just be able to use `"/script.php"` as the path for your ajax call. In javascript, starting a path with `/` takes you to the root of the server; therefore, you can just progress from there and find your script files no matter where the current page is located.

If for some reason this does not work, you can use `window.location.hostname` to get the path to the server like so:

```
var scriptUrl = window.location.hostname + "/script.php";
```

**Edit:**

Based on your comments, your path would have to be your `/something/script.php` instead of just `/script.php` for both possible solutions.

Comment: "/script.php" didn't work. You right, my script file is in the same folder as the index.php(which a javascript is included). My htaccess has a rewriterule, that write domain.com/index.php?bla=123 into domain.com/123/ .. my problem is that the GET-Parameter doesn't have to be set. Someone can access the page without any GET-Parameter(which my htaccess-file will rewrite, and make a FAKE directory). So my problem is, that i can't handle the paths in my javascript if someone calls my site like this domain.com or like this domain.com/123/.. do you know what i mean?

Comment: My first thought was yes, but somehow it doesn't really work.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I need to update my question again, sry. I have a URL like this "domain.com/something/" or "domain.com/something/123".

Comment: So your update won't solve my problem, cause i get only the hostname.

Comment: Ah well that could be your initial problem. You would have to include the something prior to the script.php :P

Comment: Like a value from a config-file? Something like the path to the script? :D

Comment: This is it, thanks. :) You know, i want to run this on multiple servers with different "subfolders". I will just create a config-file, which one of the parameter will be the direction to my script(in my case "/something").

Comment: Yep that should work for you. :) Otherwise, you could most likely come up with the path via using a variation of the window.location example I gave you.

Answer (score 1):

you can use inline condition, like this example:

```
url: (4 > 2 ? "script.php" : "../script.php"),
```

in this example you will always end up with the url "script.php", so change the `4 > 2` condition to your own needs

Comment: Is there a possibility to check which of them is available before the call?

Comment: Look, i have a htaccess file.. if i access **domain.com** i need to use the url "script.php". but if i access **domain.com/SOMEVALUE** i need to use the url "../script.php". Any ideas how to handle that in js?

Comment: @Sylnois You could easily make an if statement that check the url of the page using window.location and based on the path use the corresponding url.

Comment: This was also my first thought, but i want to use relative paths and not absolute.. any idea how to check it?

Comment: @Sylnois I am still sort of confused. Do you only have one script file? If that is the case can't you just use "/script.php" which will take you from the root of the server directory and look for the script file.