# Not show link that doesen't exist

Tags: html

I'm new to this. But maybe someone could help me?

I am using this link, product->intnotes ?>.pdf">Produktblad, for my pdf files linked to the products in my internet store and it works fine. But is there away to make the link disappear if the intnotes.pdf doesen't exist?

Comment: Use `file_exists` to check if the file exists or not?

Comment: You need a server-side script at least. Or use some kind of javascript that requests the file and if it's a 404 returned you can know if the file exists or not. But with HTML you can't make anything of this.

Comment: either use PHP's `file_exists`, or use Javascript and check out [this thread about checking if file exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473387/using-ajax-and-jquery-to-check-if-file-exists-always-returns-200-response)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(file_exists(product->intnotes.'.pdf')){

}
```